# If I remove a UILabel from superview in a Reusable cell, how can I reinitialise the UILabel in the cell when reusing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having some trouble with a reusable uitableviewcell in my uitableview. In my reusable tableviewcell xib file I have a subview with 3 uilabels. If I do not receive a particular dictionary key when populating the cell I remove the middle uilabel - the consequence of removing this label means that the associated constraints are removed and therefore the top and bottom labels will move closer to one another in the absence of the middle label. However, once i removeFromSubview in a particular cell and later dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier I receive a cell which already has the middle label removed and thus cannot display the required text. I have tried [uilabel addSubview] with constraints each time the cell is returned but without success. Any ideas would be appreciated... thanks in advance...

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not remove the view, but hide it and change its constraint so it has 0 height/width (if vertical/horizontal)  and 0 vertical/horizontal spacing, that way the constraints for the element below will adjust automatically as if the middle one was not there, and if you need it again then you set its constraints as default.

I did this on my code not long ago and works great, If you provide some code I'll could give you more details on how to do it. Are you using storyboards or working programmatically?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - simple but very effective. Worked perfectly. I thank you again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to use two different reuse identifiers instead of one: an identifier for cells with three labels, and another identifier for cells with two labels.